# How to stop detecting mouse leave if I did not click on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently creating a Windows 10 replica in HTML, CSS and JS.

While recreating the desktop area, I need to make the desktop app icons selectable. I used jquery to apply different styles to the app icons on click and mouseleave (so the background color changes when I click on it and when the mouse leaves the icon **after** the click).

I also want the icons to be able to be deselected by clicking on another icon. My code for that part works well. But there is some problem, here is what I did that made the problem appear, text in "()" stands for what my script does for the action:

- click on 1st app icon (apply "click" style for clicked icon)
- click on 2nd app icon (remove "click" style for previous icon and apply for clicked icon)
- hover on 1st app icon (nothing happens)
- mouse leave 1st app icon ("click" style is applied for 1st app icon too! <- This should not happen, nothing should happen in this situation)

I thought if it was a problem with the event listeners, I've tried to use .off() to stop it from happening but it failed.

Here is my code:

The javascript code

```
$(".desktop-app-box").on("click", function() {
        $(".desktop-app-box").css({
            "background-color": "",
            "border-color": ""
        });
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)",
            "border-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
        });
        $(this).on("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).css({
                "background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)",
                "border-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"
            });
        });
    });
    $("html, .start, .taskbar-start-btn").on("click", function() {
        $(".desktop-app-box").css({
            "background-color": "",
            "border-color": ""
        }).removeClass("dropped");
    });
    $(".desktop-app-box").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".desktop-app-box").removeClass("dropped");
    });
```

The HTML code

```
<div class="desktop">
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box desktop-app-box-large"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>TeamViewer 12</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
</div>
```

Other scripts:

- jquery 3.2.1
- jquery ui 1.12.1
- jquery 1.7.2

I've tried my best to describe the problem, please tell me if I need to clarify any part or any more information should be provided. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(edit: using classes, Vanquished Wombat's answer, is a much cleaner solution. You should definetely go with that)

Use the [event-binder `one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (which will only be called once) instead of `on`.

```js
    $(".desktop-app-box").on("click", function() {
        $(".desktop-app-box").css({
            "background-color": "",
            "border-color": ""
        });
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)",
            "border-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
        });
        $(this).one("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).css({
                "background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)",
                "border-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
.desktop {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.desktop-app-box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desktop">
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box desktop-app-box-large"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>TeamViewer 12</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><img src="icon/full-recycle-bin.ico"><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Peter - I voted yours up as it is a more succinct answer to the OP's specific bug. Though I think he could benefit from a nudge along toward a better technique that will serve him better in the long term.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, if only event-driven programming did not suffer from the law of unintended consequences.

You are making things hard for yourself by having the mouseleave listener set in the click function. Notably, you do not unset the mouseleave listener which trips you up.

I took your sample code and made a running snippet which does what I think you wanted. Note that I took the mouseleave outside the click, and created a 'selected' class to make it easier to read the code.

The technique is then one of adding the 'selected' class to anything that is selected and removing it on mouseleave. I do not need to remove the mouseleave listener because there is little overhead in running it for each such event.

There is another technique that you may find useful to consider, which is to apply classes as 'state' markers. For example, in my snippet, I could determine via code which icon is 'selected' by using $('.desktop').find('.selected'). You can add multiple classes to an element and it is legitimate to do so as a means to indicate state or similar. Just a thought.

If this is not exactly what you need then explain what you are trying to do in the context of my snippet and we can tweak it.

```js
$(".desktop-app-box")
  .on("click", function() {
        $(".desktop-app-box.running").removeClass("running");
        $(this)
          .addClass("selected");
    })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("selected")){
        $(this)
          .removeClass("selected")
          .addClass("running");
       }
    });
```

```css
/* See the selected class below.... */

/*  These classes are just to get the snippet working. */
.desktop 
{ 
width: 600px; height: 400px;background-color: #666666;margin: 10px;
}
.desktop-app-box
{
cursor: pointer;width:60px; height: 50px;padding: 5px;margin: 5px;background-color: blue;border: 2px solid white;display: inline-block;font: 12px Arial;color: white;text-align: center;
}
.desktop-app-box span 
{
margin-top: 2px;display: block;
}

/* Important: I created the selected & running classes to make assignment & removal easier with addClass() removeClass() */
.selected 
{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
color: gold;
}
.running
{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
color: lime;
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="desktop">
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>My Computer</span></div>
    <div class="desktop-app-box"><i class="fa fa-recycle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Recycle Bin</span></div>

    <div class="desktop-app-box"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>TeamViewer 12</span></div>

</div>
```